# В чем вести / генерировать тех. документацию API растущего проекта?

Tags: документация, api, проектирование

Пишем немаленький проект. Растет число разработчиков, ролей, серверов, протоколов. Хочется иметь четкую, хорошо форматированную документацию, как, [например](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories), у Google : )

В чём, и как её лучше вести и генерировать html?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Зависит от того, что именно вы хотите.

Если вопрос **об удобном формате** для написания документации, то попробуйте [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/)/[AsciiDoctor](http://asciidoctor.org/). Это plain-text формат, напоминающий Markdown и вики-разметку. Он позволяет отделить текст документации от шаблона оформления (приятные шаблоны "из коробки") и умеет собираться и в HTML, и в PDF, и в DocBook, и по всякому. Активно развивается инфраструктура вокруг него. Его удобно хранить в контроле версий (это plain-text формат, который легко диффать и мержить) и работать с ним как с исходным кодом документации.

Если вопрос **о готовой системе** хранения документации и совместной работы - посмотрите [Atlassian Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence): довольно приятная штука, много плагинов, интегрируется как с инфраструктурой Atlassian (багтерекер JIRA, билдсервер Bamboo, и т.п.) так и с популярными тулами вроде Balsamiq Mockups.

Еще доводилось пользоваться для этой цели MediaWiki, но у нее, как мне кажется, порог вхождения выше.

Если речь **об автоматизации документирования** всяких **REST API**, то я не так давно в ходе поисков нашел отличную вещь - [Swagger](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-spec). Этот проект представляет собой попытку стандартизировать описание REST службы в виде набора xml/json-документов, на основе которых можно сгенерить как ["живую" online](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/) (с возможностью подергать сервисы прямо со страницы) так и обычную offline-документацию, и заглушки для клиентской части под разные языки.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Смотрю Swagger: на первый взгляд весьма хорош. Confluence тоже вариант, тем более, что мы уже на BitBucket держим весь код.

Comment: Swagger уже давно не попытка, а вполне успешный стандарт [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/).

Comment: @NickVolynkin feel free поправить ответ )

Answer (score -1):

Пишу документацию/справочник по разрабатываемой системе.
Тоже озадачился, на чем это делать.
Нашел интересную вещь **Outwiker**
http://jenyay.net/Soft/Outwiker

Comment: Неплохо было бы, если бы Вы пояснили в ответе, какие преимущества у данного метода над другими. Спасибо.

Comment: программа только под Windows. Не годно.

Comment: программа не только под Windows